# PHP - - ini "(none)" and not loading extensions

Tags: php, mongodb, apache

So I ran into something I'm just hoping I can get some understanding on. There is a clean Centos machine with a clean install of PHP. It had the mongoDB driver installed as well. When accessing the web app through the browser, it kept complaining the mongo client didn't exist. All of the installation procedures were followed, `php.ini` contained `extension=mongo.so`, and httpd restarted. PHP `info()` did not contain the Mongo conf. What ended up working was adding a `mongo.ini` file to the `/etc/php.d` directory with the `extension=mongo.so` written to it.

I'm getting a sneaky suspicion `php.ini` wasn't being loaded correctly, but I don't understand why. The reason I'm thinking this is, for one, it worked after adding `mongo.ini`. Second, there are mismatched PHP `info()` outputs from the CLI and browser gui.

[image: cli output]

and from the GUI

[image: gui output]

Both of these were snapped seconds apart. No configuration changes or restarts were made. For some reason the CLI output says the loaded configuration file was `/etc/php.ini` which was expected. The browser GUI however shows `(none)`. What is going on here? Is this why the `extension=mongo.so` was never loading from the `php.ini` file?

**versions**

```
Apache/2.4.6
PHP/5.4.16
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611

[someUser@someServer etc]# find / -name php.ini 
/etc/php.ini
```

Is SO even the proper place for this? or should I move to a different forum?

**update**

After reading [Grigory Ilizirov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5102237/grigory-ilizirov)'s comments, and doing some research, I think the question is answered if he wants to post it. Looks like the php configs for apache wasn't being loaded. I had just assumed the `/etc/php.ini` file was all that was needed to be edited. Now I just need to figure out how the heck I'm going to do that.

***update 2***

Reverted back to a clean install and did everything again. This time around, same results from the CLI and web GUI as before, but now mongo wouldn't load at all despite being added in `/etc/php.d/mongo.ini`. suspect SELinux is interferring with apache. `mongo.ini` is no longer showing in the additional .ini file sections. Disabling SELinux and rebooting allows it to load to apache.

**FINAL**

This is indeed an SELinux issue. Now then, does this belong on SO for future users?

Comment: are you using apache ?

Comment: @GrigoryIlizirov yes. apache 2.4.6

Comment: you need to edit php.ini which is located in \apache\apahce2.4.6\bin\php.ini... php for cli and php for web are different

Comment: @GrigoryIlizirov There is no /apache directory with a php.ini. only the one in the /etc directory. Is that the "root" of the issue? `[someUser@someServer etc]# find / -name php.ini /etc/php.ini`

Comment: i did a reboot and the web gui correctly displayed the config file. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: looks like its an SELinux block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was indeed SELinux interfering with Apache's access to the PHP configuration file. Adding the security context fixed it.

```
semanage fcontext -at httpd_sys_content_t '/etc/php.ini'
semanage fcontext -at httpd_sys_content_t '/etc/php.d/(/.*)?'
restorecon -Rv /etc/
systemctl restart httpd
```

[image: apache found the config file]

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your PHP have installed MongoDB extension.try use `PHP -m` see if you have MongoDB installed.

Then Download source code from https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver-legacy.

follow these steps to install the extension:

```
tar zxvf mongo-x.x.x.tgz -C ../
cd mongo-x.x.x/
phpize
./configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/php/bin/php-config
make clean
make
make install
extension=mongo.so //add this line to php.ini
```

after install try run `PHP -m` again, see if extension installed success.

for more info, you should read PHP doc.http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.fedora

Comment: `pecl` was used to install mongo. mongo is working correctly now. What I'm trying to understand is why it only successfully worked after adding the `extension=mongo.so` to `/etc/php.d/mongo.ini` vs. just writing it to `/etc/php.ini` as you and the docs stated?